# Listen when a key is pressed in the (ios sdk)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to capture that any key is being pressed in the softkeyboard programmatically? I need to dispach an event when any key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to become a delegate for whichever responder you're using to present the keyboard.  In most cases it's just a UITextField or UITextView.  In either case, assign yourself as the delegate and respond to

[textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a)

Comment: Ok the thing is that the responder is a webview. The softkeyboard is displayed when a textarea inside a html page is touched.

Comment: I see, this is a different beast altogether then.  I don't know how to capture key presses from the web.

If you're trying to send key press events back to some native implementation then you could fire off a fake link and intercept it with the a webview delegate

- (BOOL) webView:shouldLoadRequest:.....